# Seem to lose my ssh when the monitor goes to sleep, why?

Tags: ssh, suspend, power-management

I am running Ubunut 14.04 and when the monitor goes to sleep the ssh connection is lost.  I can't figured out why these two correlated.  I had through perhaps the system was going into hibernate mode or some sort of sleep mode, but I don't think the system is going into a sleep or hibernate mode (if it does I can't figured out how to determine this).

In the "Brightness & Lock" screen the "Turn screen off when inactive for: " is configured for 5 minutes.  Lock is disabled.  "Require my password when waking from suspend" is checked and when the monitor awakes the password screen is present.  So, I think the system is going into suspend mode, but in the "Power" screen the "Suspend when inactive for" is set to "Don't suspend".

So, I am at a lost as to why I am losing my ssh connection when the monitor is going to sleep.  Thanks.

Edit: I failed to mention, I am actively using the ssh connection from another machine when I notice the monitor go dark and shortly thereafter I lose the ssh connection.

Edit: Also found out that my Samba share folder disappears within Windows.  So, now more confused than before.

Comment: Probably due to keepalive - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/ . Also use screen or tmux.

Comment: In my case, I went to Settings -> Power -> Automatic Suspend -> Off and I can now ssh into my desktop after locking the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Loosing SSH connection mostly depend on server and your process on server . As explain if monitor goes down and your Linux lock your screen it means that you didn't work with SSH connection for a while . In Linux there is argument by the name of `TMOUT` , as an example if you set `TMOUT=60` if you don't touch your console for 1 minute you will be logout . For solving this problem set *TMOUT* to reasonable variable .

In ssh daemon config on server , there is `TCPKeepAlive` variable which try to keeping connection up .

```
$ vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And uncomment `TCPKeepAlive yes` to tell the service to try keeping alive connection .

Comment: I did check the `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`file and the `TCPKeepAlive` setting was set to `yes`.  I didn't state it explicitly, so I will update the description, but I am actively interacting with the ssh connection from another machine and when I see the screen go dark the ssh connection will go down shortly thereafter.

Comment: what about `TMOUT` ? try `echo $TMOUT` on your machine .

Comment: Sorry about that, I did check TMOUT and it does't seem to be defined.  I will set it to something like 60 minutes and see if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome . If it works , try `export TMOUT` to  set permanently .

Comment: ssh parameters `-o TCPKeepAlive="yes"` and `-o ServerAliveInterval="60"` seems to help.